# How to change whole css file using a button or switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cookies

Suppose I have 2 stylesheets, dark.css and light.css . I want to allow the user to switch between these two themes in the homepage and set it as default to other pages too. My website also contains many other css files which are almost same for both themes( otherwise it would be a problem!!)

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet#Notes, then try something and come back.

Answer (score 0):

We should never switch or unload `css` file in order to do such things. It is better to switch a class in `html` or `body` element.

For example - 
First of all load both `css` style file. Then for `dark.css`, wrap all your styles under root class `dark` just like below -

```
.dark .style1{
 ...
}

.dark .style2{
  ...
}
```

Same for `light.css`

```
.light .style1{
 ...
}

.light .style2{
  ...
}
```

And then switch the class of `body` tag using below JavaScript -

```
<button id="dark">Dark theme</button>
<button id="light">Light theme</button>
```

```
let body = document.body;

let darkBtn = document.getElementById('dark');
let lightBtn = document.getElementById('light');

darkBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    body.classList.remove('light');
    body.classList.add('dark');
});

lightBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    body.classList.remove('dark');
    body.classList.add('light');
});
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/3xKxgP8Ow